# Вывод с разных таблиц, определённые столбцы из mysql в таблицу html при помощи php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Привет друзья, помогите справиться с задачей, имеются в СУБД MySQL база в которой есть 3 таблиц, в первой таблице есть столбцы (id, name), во второй таблице (name, value) то есть какое то значение привязано логически с именем. (Скажу сразу что имена одинаковы во всех таблицах). в третьей таблице аналогично как и со второй таблицей.

```
<table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Value из 2 таблицы</th>
                <th>Value из 3 таблицы</th>                        
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Задача такова: как вывести в html таблицу все значения из всех таблиц, сравнивая со столбцом имён первой таблицы (id, name) с последующими таблицами (столбцом name)

> Если в колонке name из table1 совпадает с name из table2 или c name из table3 , ТО выводим в html таблицу наше совпадение в соответствии с колонкой (Value из 2 таблицы ИЛИ Value из 3 таблицы).

[image: TABLE1]

[image: TABLE2]

Comment: В SQL запросе делаете LEFT JOIN обоих таблиц с данными и выдаете `coalesce(Tab2.name, Tab3.name)` только решаете вопросы уникальности записей, если вдруг в table2 или 3 более чем одна запись с одинаковым именем

Comment: а если там будет больше чем одна запись? он будет перезаписывать её?

Comment: тогда выходных записей станет больше одной, если вы не примете меры для подавления дублей

Comment: Во врой (и третьей) таблице может ли оказаться например "Время" 2 раза ? Могут ли быть в первой таблице фразы, которых нет во второй (и третьей) таблице и если да, то должны ли такие строки попадать в результат (с пустыми полями value2 и value3

Comment: Да, их может не быть, если их нету что можно пустым оставить либо присвоить что "Пусто" как заглушка.

Comment: тогда что то в этом роде https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mdvBMUXcN1GnPds1oFhXMA/2  только вы не сказали, может ли быть более одного значения с одной фразой и если да, то какое из значений интересует

Comment: Повторений не может быть. Предусмотрено.

Comment: ну тогда тот запрос вполне рабочий.

Comment: Сейчас попробую его

Comment: в общем я протестировал этот запрос, мне нужно выводить по list_project_id_positions, добавил условие WHERE list_project_id_positions = 'нужный идентификатор'. то на первый взгляд вроде нормально, но если попадутся одинаковые слова во второстепенных таблицах то начинается дубляж

Comment: Смысл такой когда я на странице нажимаю на запись (запись из table1) то он должен мне вывести в таблице html, информацию о ней (информация выводятся из второстепенных таблиц) логично сделать тогда WHERE и требуемый столбец

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите. я спросил, могут ли повторятся значения для одной фразы, вы ответили "_Повторений не может быть. Предусмотрено._", а потом говорите "_но если попадутся одинаковые слова во второстепенных таблицах то начинается дубляж_". Очевидно что во второстепенных таблицах если есть повторы, то получаемое value вероятно разное, тогда встает вопрос какое именно value нужно, если их несколько

Comment: В каждой из 3 таблиц есть особый идентификатор под названием -> list_project_id_positions, он связывает таблицы а именно нужные строки.

Comment: Тот который list_project_id_positions я получаю, при помощи него можно вывести все записи, даже если будут одинаковые название и значения во  второстепенных таблицах list_project_id_positions будет у записи уникальный

Comment: SELECT Current_postions.phrase, Current_postions.geo, yandex.positions AS yandexs,
       google.positions AS googles,
       google_mobile.positions AS google_mobiles
 FROM Current_postions
 LEFT JOIN yandex ON Current_postions.phrase = yandex.phrase 
 LEFT JOIN google ON Current_postions.phrase = google.phrase
 LEFT JOIN google_mobile ON Current_postions.phrase = google_mobile.phrase
 WHERE Current_postions.list_project_id_positions = 'тот самый уникальный идентификатор'

Comment: Я подумал что если я укажу уникальный идентификатор то дублирования строк не будет, т.к указана конкретная строка. Видимо нет, извиняюсь за мою неточность

Comment: ну так если в таблицах помимо фразы должен совпадать еще и list_project_id_positions  так и укажите его сравнение в условиях ON

Comment: Часть дубликатов только отсеяло при указали дополнительного условия

Answer (score 1):

инициализируем PDO или другой класс для работи с БД (показываю на примере PDO )

```
$db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
```

запрос

```
$sql = 'SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.val AS value1,
   table3.val AS value2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.name = table3.name WHERE table1.name = table2.name OR table1.name = table3.name';
```

получаем результат запроса

```
$result_statement = db->query($sql);
$result = $result_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

теперь у нас результат в виде массива значений

итерируемся через каждый элемент и записываем его в таблицу

```
foreach ($result as $res) {
            $table .= " <tr>
            <td>$res[id]</td>
            <td>$res[name]</td>
            <td>$res[value1]</td>
            <td>$res[value2]</td>
        </tr>";
        }
```

добавляем `$table` в html код

Comment: Ваш запрос абсолютно не рабочий. во первых, если в таблице 2 или 3 не окажется записи с каким то именем (а судя по условиям задачи имя обычно присутствует только в одной из таблиц) то запрос ничего не найдет, ибо inner... Во вторых, если скажем с таблице 3 окажется запись с знаком '%' в поле то такая запись будет совпадать с _любой_ записью из tab1, потому как like... и в третьих в коментариях к вопросу ТС намекал что какие то имена в таблице 2 или 3 могут дублироваться, если это так ваш запрос может помножить записи

Comment: Во первых: я дал человеку ответ на конкретный вопрос который он задал "как вывести в html таблицу все значения из всех таблиц, сравнивая со столбцом имён первой таблицы (id, name) с последующими таблицами (столбцом name)"

Comment: Имена всегда присутствуют как в первой так и в последующих таблицах. И да, при использовании такого запроса - идёт дублирование значений, напоминающее как "всевозможные варианты значение имени"

Comment: и среди этих дубликатов есть истинные записи

Comment: @АндрейСуворов Так на ваш вопрос правильно ответить в принципе невозможно, потому что вы не привели примера исходных данных в таблицах. по вопросу даже не было ясно, что имена присутствуют всегда. А раз записей много, то вам для начала надо решить какое из value вы хотите видеть для конкретного имени

Comment: @Mike  Во вторых:  Здесь не место обсуждать все исключения что могут случиться в результате выполнения кода. В третьих: "если в таблице 2 или 3 не окажется записи с каким то именем то запрос ничего не найдет?" да ладно?

Comment: @Mike если Вы не поняли суть вопроса это не повод ставить -1 в ответах

Comment: @AndriyPoplavskiy да, я не заметил OR. но он вообще приводит к катастрофе. все записи перемножаются на все. что и наблюдает сейчас у себя ТС.

Comment: @Mike для таких случаев существует DISTINCT.   P.S. пожалуйста перед тем как комментировать внимательно прочитайте ответ

Comment: Загрузил screenshots

Comment: Третья таблица такая же как на втором скриншоше

Comment: Phrase как Name

Comment: @AndriyPoplavskiy Ок, вот я пример сделал https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pp4iydHuNqNUTQUq7RcX9B/0  можете попробовать добавить distinct все равно совершенно левые данные будут в выборке

Comment: ну да, вижу, всё равно дубликаты присутствовают.
ну если вы не до конца поняли мою суть задачи, я смогу ещё раз пояснить.
исходя вот из скриншотов и из html таблицы которой я присылал, нужно сравнить phrase из главной таблицы со второстепенными таблицами в которой есть  phrase и positions и если совпадут Phare двух таблиц, то в таблице html выводим значение positions